# Clarification on scene graph implementation. Adding object/node to a root node or container?

Tags: opengl, c++, data-structure, scene-graph, imgui

I learned about scene graphs from [this chapter](https://learnopengl.com/Guest-Articles/2021/Scene/Scene-Graph) on learnopengl and using this I'm trying to make a simple imgui window that can display the scene graph, but one thing that wasn't made clear/I'm having trouble understanding is would I want a container that holds all the entities/nodes or would I want to create a root node and eevrything gets added to that?

This is some of the code in the chapter I assume this is would be my "node"

```
class  Entity {
public:
    // Scene graph
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<Entity>> children;
    Entity* parent = nullptr;

    template<typename... TArgs>
    void AddChild(TArgs&... args) {
        children.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Entity>(args...));
        children.back()->parent = this;
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm using it

```
    Entity scenegraph; // root node
    scenegraph.name = "Root";

    scenegraph.AddChild(std::move(someEntity));
```

But I'm not sure if it would be more typical to do something like this instead `std::vector<Entity> scenegraph`

Comment: "More typical" is usually not the real goal we're working toward, just a proxy for something like "easier to work with / scale to real games" or "better performing". Both the approaches you show *can* work. Do you prefer working in one style or the other, or have you run any tests indicating an unwanted performance bottleneck in one approach or another?